# RewriteRule not working for some links in XAMPP apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteRule ^home/?$ pages/forum_html.php [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^forum-thread/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ pages/forum_thread_gen_html.php?thread_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

I am trying to do an internal URL redirect. The first RewriteRule works fine but the second doesn't work, the page shows object not found but when I change the second line to `^forum-thread/?$` the page displays but of course no id for my page to process.

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening?

The second URL looks like this:

```
localhost/rootfolder/projectfolder/forum-thread/cdjd2_dsdsd4_adsda/
```

Comment: Could you please give an example URL you request that should be rewritten by that command?

Comment: An example url of what you're trying to capture will great.

Comment: Bit of a guess but... it sounds like the second rule **is** working, but you perhaps have a relative URL issue with images, CSS and/or JS?

Comment: I finally figured out the problem. The url had underscores and the pattern matching sequence I used did not have an underscore in it. I have edited the second RewriteRule as so: RewriteRule ^forum-thread/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ pages/forum_thread_gen_html.php?thread_id=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: @FananDala If you had included the request URL in your initial question then that would have been an easy spot. You should add that as an answer and accept time (you may have to wait a short while before you can accept it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `URL` had underscores and the pattern matching sequence I used did not have an underscore in it. I have edited the second RewriteRule as so: 
`RewriteRule ^forum-thread/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ pages/forum_thread_gen_html.php?thread_id=$1 [NC,L]`